# Proving discontinuity with $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition and topological continuity definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me if the following proofs of discontinuity of function $\mu$ are correct.

Take function $\mu:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$

such that:

$$\mu = \begin{cases}0, & x\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\\ x-\frac{1}{2}, & x>\frac{1}{2}.\end{cases}$$

Then I devised two ways to prove the discontinuity of this function, that I would be glad someone could verify:

1. $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof

Taking $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
$\forall \epsilon>0$,
let $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+$
and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+\::\:\alpha<\delta$

The defining $y=x+\alpha$, implies:

$$\lvert y-x\rvert<\delta.$$

Then $\lvert\mu(y)-\mu(x)\rvert=\mu(\frac{1}{2}+\alpha)-0=\frac{1}{2}-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}=\alpha$.

Hence the function is not continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$.

2. General topology proof:
   Taking the open interval $(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$,$\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)$, for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, then:

$$\mu^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)=[0,\frac{1}{2}]$$ and

$$
\mu^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)=(\frac{1}{2},+\infty).$$
Hence:

$$\mu^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cup (\frac{1}{2},+\infty)$$

which is not an open set. Hence, the function $\mu$ is discontinuous at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $\mu$ *is* continuous (draw its graph).

Comment: @AnneBauval       Thanks for your quick reply!I drew its graph, but there is a jump at $\frac{1}{2}$, right? How do you prove its continuity?

Comment: There is no jump.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you point out the mistake in my proof?

Comment: In proof 1: the last sentence. In proof 2: every equality. Btw, did you correct your graph?

Comment: TeX note: the - in $\delta$-$\epsilon$ is a hyphen -, not a minus sign $-$; so it should be entered as $\delta$-$\epsilon$ `$\delta$-$\epsilon$`, not $\delta-\epsilon$ `$\delta-\epsilon$`.  Also, in `{cases}`, you should use `&` to set off the condition.  I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The definition of limit is: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y-x|<\delta$. So, assume $|y-1/2|<\delta$. Then, $|\mu(y)-\mu(1/2)|=|\mu(y)|$. If $y \leq 1/2$, then $\mu(y)=0 < \epsilon$. If $y>1/2$ then $|\mu(y)|=|y-1/2|<\delta=\epsilon$. So, $\mu$ is continuous at $1/2$.
2. You have the preimages wrong. If you take $(1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon)$ its preimage would be $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ which is open.